# Guest user's role not visible in Azure Active Directory auth token claims

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I am building an application that uses Microsoft Authentication Library(MSAL) to manage user authentication. I have been testing inviting users and applying app roles to them using AAD enterprise applications. When a user from outside of the application's directory, (A generic microsoft account), logs into the application they are not receiving any role claims in their auth token.

I have tried turning off the setting in external collaboration settings that says *"Guest users permissions are limited"* but this has not made a difference.

I would appreciate any help, Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` as the authority, it won't do the authentication against the tenant. Because personal Microsoft account doesn't have a tenant. The account will be treated as MSA rather than a guest user of your tenant.

So you need to force your personal Microsoft account to authenticate against specific tenant by setting authority as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant}`, the roles will be added to the claims.

Comment: This is basically correct. The role claims should be in the token if you use tenant specific endpoint.

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Could you help me, i can extract role from token ID, but roles aren't still presented in access token, what I did wrong? How did you resolve this?

Comment: @VladimirTopolev To make app role exist in access token, you should define the app role in the app registration which represents the service / backend / API side, not in client side app registration.

Comment: Am I correct, right now I've registered only one Platform for SPA, I need to add another platform responsible for me server as well?

Comment: @VladimirTopolev If you have an API application, you need to create an app registration as well for it. But if you are calling some official API (eg. Microsoft Graph), it's impossible to define the app role to access token.

Comment: @AllenWu Probably you could help where I may find tutorial where explain how to build SPA and REST API protected by Azure AD (server is written in NodeJS). As I understand  I need 
1. to get access token in SPA, if FE needs to use roles like SuperAdmin - it's available in ID Token
2. then I need to invoke my REST API, validate this token some how (don't know how, couldn't find any tutorials). I thought actually when I validate this token on server I would may use roles in token payload which isn't presented :(

Comment: @VladimirTopolev See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles.